# How to call the method successively in C#?

Tags: c#

I saw this code typed in java.

```
PersonInfo result = personInfoBuilder
            .setName("MISTAKE")
            .setAge(20)
            .setFavoriteAnimal("cat")
            .setFavoriteColor("black")
            .setName("JDM")
            .setFavoriteNumber(7)
            .build();
```

and I tried in C# this way.

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonBuilder
{
    private PersonInfo _personElement = null;

    private int age;
    private string name;

    public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PersonInfo GetPerson()
    {
        _personElement = _personElement ?? new PersonInfo();
        _personElement.Age = age;
        _personElement.Name = name;

        return _personElement;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonBuilder builder = new PersonBuilder();
        builder.SetName("he")
               .SetAge(20);

    }
}
```

and I have a error [Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.],

How can I call the method successively in C# like a Java ?

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: *"I saw a motorbike cutting corners and I tried it with my car but it didn't work"*

Comment: Create a class `PersonInfoBuilder`, initialize an instance, let every method return this instance, then you can chain it. The `Build`-method returns the instance of `PersonInfo` with the specified properties.

Comment: The keyword to search for is **fluent api** or **fluent interface**. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface and https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Comment: You can achieve it by using c# extension methods, although I cannot understand why you need to do it like in this java example

Comment: @OrElseIt looks simpler than C# code to me.

Comment: @SirRufo thanks to your answer that I look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you suggested is called builder pattern. Here is how I do builder pattern in my C# codes.

Builder class

```
class PersonInfo
    {
        private string name, animan, color;
        private int age, num;

        private PersonInfo() { }

        public class Builder
        {
            PersonInfo info = new PersonInfo();

            public Builder setName(string name) { info.name = name; return this; }
            public Builder setAge(int age) { info.age = age; return this; }
            public Builder setFavoriteAnimal(string animan) { info.animan = animan; return this; }
            public Builder setFavoriteColor(string color) { info.color = color; return this; }
            public Builder setFavoriteNumber(int num) { info.num = num; return this; }

            public PersonInfo build()
            {
                return info;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is how you can use it.

```
PersonInfo.Builder personInfoBuilder = new PersonInfo.Builder();
PersonInfo result = personInfoBuilder
                                    .setName("MISTAKE")
                                    .setAge(20)
                                    .setFavoriteAnimal("cat")
                                    .setFavoriteColor("black")
                                    .setName("JDM")
                                    .setFavoriteNumber(7)
                                    .build();
```